# Can not Resolve React Native Camera MLKit Dependencies RN 0.62.0

Tags: react-native, gradlew, react-native-camera

**React Native: 0.62.0**

**react-native-camera: git+https://git@github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera.git**

My app runs fine using react-native run-android but when I try to generate the .apk it fails with the following error

**Error Message:**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.native-camera:mlkitReleaseCompileClasspath > Resolve dependencies of :react-native-camera:mlkitReleaseRu
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-camera:compileMlkitReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':react-native-camera:mlkitReleaseCompileClasspath'.
>   Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:12.0.1.
>        Required by:
>            project :react-native-camera
>   Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:12.0.1.
>        Required by:
>            project :react-native-camera

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings